# Flash Air to windows tablet

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

i'm making an application in Flash Air(Flash cc 2014). It's an application where you can swipe between pages. But the application needs to be working on a windows tablet.

So I've tried to do: AIR 16.0 for Desktop => AIR 16.0 Desktop Settings

http://downloads.unides.be/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-25%20at%2014.02.16.png

When I publish this, I only see this in the structure:

http://downloads.unides.be/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-25%20at%2014.03.23.png

But I think I need to have an .exe -file? Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong? (I've opened all the folders, but none of these have an exe-file)

Comment: But why did you not publish it as an ".air" file ( AIR package ) which is runnable everywhere you have AIR installed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you publish an application using MAC, the exported file will be .app or .dmg
Or you export your application using a PC, or you can try exporting projector files using Flash CC/2014.
You can also export a .AIR file and will be hybrid.

To export Projector files from Flash Pro CC, do the following:

1) In Flash Pro CC, select Commands > Export as Projector.

2) On the Export as Projector dialog, click Browse to navigate to and specify a location where you want to save the Projector file.

3) Select any of the following options:

1. Windows to create a .exe file that can be run on Windows PC.
2. MAC to create a .app file that can be run on MAC.

4) Click Export to export the Projector file.

[image]

*Export As Projector dialog accessed from Commands > Export as Projector.*